# Python Web Scraping: How to get HTML of an internal site

Tags: python, web-scraping

My organization has something similar to an internal LinkedIn, where employees list out descriptions, skills, alignment, job title, etc.

I am trying to write a web scraping program that can pull all of this text down to search for key terms, pull key info, and images. I feel comfortable doing the parcing and analysis, but am struggling to get past my organizations access requirements to actually pull the HTML code for each of my 1000 employees.

Is it possible to write my python script to run in the foreground (aka the chrome/firefox window that I have open that is already signed in and can access everyone's pages) and then loop through everyone's site links? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Isn't that data stored in a database owned by your organization? Why reinvent the wheel? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with Selenium lib.

Selenium is a lib that can do tests and other nice things in browser layer.

Doc: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Oficial doc: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/

I hope help you

Good Luck